# Как убрать виджет с некоторых страниц без плагина?

Tags: wordpress, виджет

Подскажите, как убрать через код (php) без плагина виджет с некоторых страниц сайта на WordPress? Сейчас он отображается в правом сайдбаре. Нужно, чтобы виджет оставался только в сайдбаре на главной странице сайта, а на остальных его не было. В каком файле нужно прописать изменения и какие? Спасибо.

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/is_front_page

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, ваш виджет называется archives. Тогда вот такой код в functions.php покажет его только на главной.

```
add_filter('sidebars_widgets', 'hidemywidget');
function hidemywidget($all_widgets) {
    // скрываем везде, кроме главной
    if (!(is_front_page() || is_home())) {
        foreach ($all_widgets['primary-widget-area'] as $i => $inst) {
            // проверяем, есть ли такой виджет archives
            $pos = strpos($inst, 'archives');      
            if($pos !== false) {
                // удаляем этот виджет
                unset($all_widgets['primary-widget-area'][$i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $all_widgets;
}
```

Comment: Это тема - "Как убрать виджет с некоторых страниц без плагина?"
А это ответ - "Тогда вот такой код в functions.php покажет его только на главной"
И где логика??!!

Comment: @Константин А надо всего лишь уметь читать не только заголовок. Помогаю: " Нужно, чтобы виджет оставался только в сайдбаре на главной странице сайта, а на остальных его не было".